# Retornando id do banco de dados em uma variável global. Como corrigir?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

Após comando `insert`, eu consigo recuperar o id gerado pelo banco de dados usando uma variável global `public static int returnID`. Mas não achei muito legal essa parte de deixar a variável `static`. Teria outro jeito de recuperar essa informação? Código abaixo:

---

Minha tela:

```
public class TelaPrincipal extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel panelPrincipal,panelCenter,panelButton;
    JLabel idlbl,nomelbl,sexolbl,rglbl,cpflbl,dtnasclbl,dtcadlbl,estcivlbl;
    JTextField idField,nomeField,sexoField,rgField,cpfField,dtnascField,dtcadField,estcivField;
    JButton btnCad,btnLimpar,btnFechar;

    public TelaPrincipal(){
        UtilTelas.iniciarTelas(300, 300, "Cadastro de Pessoa", this);
        panelPrincipal = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(panelPrincipal);

        Center();
        Button();

        this.setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    private void Center(){      
        panelCenter = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));  
        JPanel gridLayout = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int fieldX = 0;
        int fieldY = 0;

        idlbl = new JLabel("Código : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(idlbl,gbc);

        nomelbl = new JLabel("Nome : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(nomelbl,gbc);

        sexolbl = new JLabel("Sexo : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(sexolbl,gbc);

        rglbl = new JLabel("RG : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(rglbl,gbc);

        cpflbl = new JLabel("CPF : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(cpflbl,gbc);

        dtnasclbl = new JLabel("Dt Nasci : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(dtnasclbl,gbc);

        dtcadlbl = new JLabel("Dt Cadastro : ");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(dtcadlbl,gbc);

        estcivlbl = new JLabel("Estado Civil");
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = ++y;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridLayout.add(estcivlbl,gbc);

        idField = new JTextField(5);
        gbc.gridx = ++fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(idField,gbc);

        nomeField = new JTextField(20);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(nomeField,gbc);

        sexoField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(sexoField,gbc);

        rgField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(rgField,gbc);

        cpfField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(cpfField,gbc);

        dtnascField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(dtnascField,gbc);

        dtcadField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(dtcadField,gbc);

        estcivField = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.gridx = fieldX;
        gbc.gridy = ++fieldY;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridLayout.add(estcivField,gbc);

        panelCenter.add(gridLayout);

        panelPrincipal.add(panelCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private void Button(){

        panelButton = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        btnCad = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        btnCad.addActionListener(this);
        panelButton.add(btnCad);

        panelPrincipal.add(panelButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(btnCad == e.getSource()){

            ControllerPessoa ControlPessoa = new ControllerPessoa();
            Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
            pessoa.setPes_nome(nomeField.getText());
            pessoa.setPes_sexo(sexoField.getText());

            try {
                if(ControlPessoa.cadastroPessoa(pessoa)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastroado com Sucesso");
                    idField.setText(String.valueOf(PessoaDAO.returnID));
                }
            } catch (HeadlessException erro) {
                erro.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException erro) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO de DriverManager Banco de Dados" +erro.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException erro) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO de Banco de Dados" +erro.getMessage());
            }       
        }
    }

}
```

---

Classe `ControllerPessoa`:

```
public class ControllerPessoa {

    public boolean cadastroPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        PessoaDAO pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();  
        String sql = "INSERT INTO farmacia.pessoa1 (nome,sexo) VALUES ('"+ pessoa.getPes_nome() +"','"+ pessoa.getPes_sexo() +"')";

        if(pessoaDAO.insert(sql)){
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }       
}
```

---

Classe `DAO`:

```
public abstract class DAO {

    public abstract boolean insert (String SQL);
    public abstract boolean update (String SQL);
    public abstract boolean delete (String SQL);
    public abstract boolean select (String SQL);
}
```

---

Classe `PessoaDAO`:

```
public class PessoaDAO extends DAO {

    PreparedStatement pstm;
    private Connection con;
    public static int returnID;

    public PessoaDAO() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        BD db = new BD();
        con = db.getConn();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(String SQL) {
        try {       
            pstm = con.prepareStatement(SQL,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);   
            pstm.execute();
            int result = pstm.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = pstm.getGeneratedKeys();         
            if (rs.next()){     
                returnID = rs.getInt("id"); // teria outro modo de recuperar o id? sem usa static?
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID : "+ returnID);
             }
             return result > 0;         

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO : inserir novo pessoa " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(String SQL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(String SQL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean select(String SQL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem como colocar só o código que é importante para pergunta? É complicado ficar revisando código atrás de problemas e melhorias.

Comment: tem sim desculpa, só da uma olhada no class PessoaDAO
é lá que esta variável static int, atraves dela eu recupero ID gerado pelo banco.

Comment: Visto que `Pessoa` é um objeto, ao invés de retornar um `boolean` no método de inserir você pode retornar um objeto `Pessoa` (ou `null` caso algo tenha saído errado). Assim, no momento de colocar no `JTextField` vai bastar um `Integer.toString(pessoa.getId());`.

Comment: Uma forma é fazer o método `insert` retornar um inteiro, no caso o ID gerado. Aí não precisa da variável estática.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Respeite as convenções de nomenclatura. Renomeie as seguintes variáveis e métodos:

   - `Center` na classe `TelaPrincipal` -> `center`
   - `Button` na classe `TelaPrincipal` -> `button`
   - `SQL` como parâmetro dos métodos do `DAO` e `PessoaDAO` -> `sql`
   - `getPes_nome` na classe `Pessoa` -> `getNome`
   - `setPes_nome` na classe `Pessoa` -> `setNome`
   - `getPes_sexo` na classe `Pessoa` -> `getSexo`
   - `setPes_sexo` na classe `Pessoa` -> `setSexo`
   - `ControlPessoa` no método `actionPerformed` da classe `TelaPrincipal` -> `controlPessoa`.
2. A responsabilidade sobre a instrução SQL pertence ao DAO e não ao controller. Uma instrução SQL é um detalhe de como a persistência e o acesso aos dados é realizado, o que está além do escopo do controller que é gerenciar o fluxo da aplicação.
3. O seu código sofre com problema de injeção de SQL. Com isso, eu poderia atacar a sua aplicação ao tentar inserir uma pessoa com o seguinte nome:
   `x','x'); DROP TABLE farmacia.pessoa1; --`
   E então o seu banco de dados já era.
4. Você não está finalizando o `Connection`, o `PreparedStatement` e o `ResultSet` adequadamente. O ideal é usar a sintaxe *try-with-resources* do Java 7 ou superior para lidar com esta situação.
5. Você está executando o `insert` duas vezes:

```java
pstm.execute();
int result = pstm.executeUpdate();
```

Antes de continuarmos ao ponto principal da sua pergunta, vamos corrigir estes problemas acima. Para isso você vai ter que alterar o método `insert` do `PessoaDAO`:

```java
public boolean insert(String nome, String sexo) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO farmacia.pessoa1 (nome, sexo) VALUES (?, ?)";
    BD db = new DB();
    try (Connection con = db.getConn(); PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        pstm.setString(1, nome);
        pstm.setString(2, sexo);
        int result = pstm.executeUpdate();
        try (ResultSet rs = pstm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                returnID = rs.getInt("id"); // teria outro modo de recuperar o id? sem usa static?
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID : "+ returnID);
            }
        }
        return result > 0;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERRO : inserir novo pessoa " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

E também o construtor, que se torna vazio:

```
public PessoaDAO() {
}
```

E então você pode (leia-se: "deve") remover o campo `pstm` e `con` da classe `PessoaDAO`.

6. O `insert` falhar é uma situação excepcional que não deveria acontecer se não houver alguma coisa errada, não acha? Neste caso, ao invés de retornar `true` ou `false` para indicar se deu certo ou errado, o ideal seria lançar uma exceção caso tenha dado errado. E isso te libera o valor de retorno para devolver o código do cliente inserido, resolvendo o problema que você solicitou.
7. Não misture lógica de visualização com lógica de infraestrutura. No caso, imagina que no futuro você queira portar o sistema para um ambiente web. O ideal seria que você não precisasse alterar uma única vírgula nos seus `DAO`s. Entretanto, aquele `JOptionPane` fará com que as coisas não funcionem como o esperado. Porém, você usa o `JOptionPane` apenas para mostrar a exceção, o ideal é lançar a exceção para ela ser tratada em uma camada superior.

Vamos arrumar os dois problemas acima. Primeiro definimos uma exceção personalizada:

```java
public class DAOException extends Exception {
    public DAOException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public DAOException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

E então utilizamos no código e resolvemos estes dois problemas:

```java
public int insert(String nome, String sexo) throws DAOException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO farmacia.pessoa1 (nome, sexo) VALUES (?, ?)";
    BD db = new DB();
    try (Connection con = db.getConn(); PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        pstm.setString(1, nome);
        pstm.setString(2, sexo);
        int result = pstm.executeUpdate();
        try (ResultSet rs = pstm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getInt("id");
            }
        }
        throw new DAOException("Não foi possível obter o id da pessoa inserida.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new DAOException("Driver do banco de dados não encontrado.", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException("Erro no banco de dados ao inserir nova pessoa.", e);
    }
}
```

E na classe `PessoaDAO`, você pode remover o campo `returnID` da classe, que era o que você queria. :)

O seu controller fica assim:

```java
public class ControllerPessoa {
    public int cadastroPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) throws DAOException {
        PessoaDAO pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();
        return pessoaDAO.insert(pessoa.getNome(), pessoa.getSexo());
    }       
}
```

E na sua classe `TelaPrincipal`:

```java
        try {
            int returnID = controlPessoa.cadastroPessoa(pessoa);
            idField.setText(String.valueOf(returnID));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastrado com Sucesso");
        } catch (HeadlessException erro) {
            erro.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DAOException erro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, erro.getMessage());
        }
```

8. Após fazer estas alterações, a sua superclasse `DAO` não será compatível com a subclasse `PessoaDAO`. Qual é a melhor solução? Bem, acho que a melhor solução e simplesmente remover a classe `DAO`. O motivo disso é que você nunca utiliza uma referência à superclasse, apenas referências à subclasse. Neste caso, você também não está tendo nenhum tipo de vantagem na prática por fazer a subclasse aderir ao formato da superclasse. Logo, a sua superclasse é inútil e você pode remover o `extends DAO` da subclasse, bem como as anotações `@Override`.
9. A sua classe `TelaPrincipal` implementa o `ActionListener` do botão. Isso é um *anti-pattern*, pois você está delegando a lógica de gerenciar o clique no botão a tela como um todo. Isso fica pior se houver vários botões, pois ao invés de você ter os gerenciadores naturalmente separados, você acabaria juntando todos em uma coisa só para depois separar usando um código espaguete cheio de `if`s e `switch`es. Enfim, isso trata-se de uma violação do modelo de programação orientada a objetos. A solução para isso é delegar o `ActionListener` corretamente.

A minha sugestão é fazer o seguinte:

```java
private void botaoCadastroClicado(ActionEvent e) {
    // Não precisa do `if(btnCad == e.getSource())` para verificar qual foi o botão.
    // O resto do código.
}
```

E então você adiciona o `ActionListener` ao botão assim, se estiver com o Java 7:

```java
btnCad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        botaoCadastroClicado(e);
    }
});
```

Ou desta forma muito mais simples no Java 8:

```java
btnCad.addActionListener(this::botaoCadastroClicado);
```

10. Os campos da sua classe `TelaPrincipal` deveriam ter o modificador `private`.
11. Não gosto de `GridBagLayout`. Veja [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuLaxbFKAcc) para entender o porquê. Mas para ser sincero não sei se este bug foi ou não corrigido (o google me deu informações conflitante e contraditórias e não tenho condições de testar isso agora).

Suas alternativas neste quesito são:

- Deixar como está.
- [Usar o `BoxLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962496/swing-gridbaglayout-with-screen-resizing).
- Usar este workaround simples que achei [neste link](http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1307039502000):

```java
public class PreferredGridBagLayout extends GridBagLayout {
    @Override
    protected GridBagLayoutInfo getLayoutInfo(Container parent, int sizeflag) {
        return super.getLayoutInfo(parent, PREFERREDSIZE);
    }
}
```

- Implementar o seu próprio gerenciador de layout.
- Usar o `BorderLayout` e em algumas partes, talvez você possa utilizar `Container`s ou `JContainer`s intermediários com `FlowLayout` e `GridLayout`.
- Usar o gerenciador de layout `null` e fazer posicionamento absoluto com os métodos `setBounds`, `setPosition` e `setSize`.
- Usar algum outro workaround que você inventar ou achar.

Enfim, há várias possibilidades. Mas como este não é o foco da pergunta, não vou me delongar mais aqui.

12. Considere usar um `enum` para o sexo, seria muito mais apropriado do que `String`s.

NOTA: Ah sim, estou imaginando que o `ClassNotFoundException` e o `SQLException` da classe `BD` venham do método `getConn` e não do construtor da classe `BD`. Se vier do construtor da classe `BD`, você vai precisar de um `try` a mais no método `insert`. Também estou assumindo que não há problema em se criar múltiplas instâncias deste objeto, uma vez que era o que você fazia indiretamente ao criar o controller e o DAO sempre que o botão de inserção fosse clicado. Se houver algum problema com isso, poste a sua classe `BD` para darmos uma olhada.

Comment: Code Review **:P**

Comment: Obg Victor estarei arrumando gostei da dicas, nunca irei acha algo assim :D... agora sobre gridbag eu vídeo aqui rachei... qual layout vc recomendaria? estou usando eclipse sem nenhum interface gráficas de arrasta e cola.

Comment: @DiegoAngelo Editei a resposta.